# How to Organize Layout Resource Files in Android Studio?

Tags: android, file, android-layout, android-studio, kotlin

To Organize Java or Kotlin Files we have packages so java/kt files can be organized nicely by importing from other packages, How to Organize layout resource files in Android Studio? Suppose i am working with 50 resource files, that will become mess? How to organize them properly?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) should help you understanding how to structure your resources.

The location of your `res` folder is typically on the same layer as your `java/kt` folder

Comment: Well i am already familiar with this, i just want to know about Layout folder, can we add sub directories to organize layouts in layout folder? if so, then how? and if not then why not?